# Why is my Nginx location rule not taking precedence?

Tags: nginx

I have a PHP application (Wordpress) in the root folder of my site, and all requests to the site run through it happily.

However, I have a subfolder, _links, which I would like to use to execute another, different php script.

Eg, if a user goes to site.com/_links/221312, then the index.php script from /_links takes over.

I formerly used a .htaccess file to achieve this, but since moving to nginx I can't make it work.

Here is the old .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?linkid=$1    [NC,L]
```

Obviously, I'm passing the last bit of the URL to the script as a parameter.

Here is my nginx config. Requests to eg site.com/_links/23423 are picked up by `if (!-e $request_filename)` and rewritten to `/index.php?q=/_links/23423` instead of being picked up by the location block.

```
server {
        listen  127.0.0.1:8080;
        server_name site.com www.site.com m.site.com;

        root /var/www/site;
        location ^~ /_links/ {
                add_header location 1;
                root /var/www/site/_links;
                rewrite "^([0-9]+)/?$" /index.php?linkid=$1 break;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        include fastcgi_params;

                }

        }
        index index.php index.html;
        if (!-e $request_filename)
            {
                rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
            }
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/site.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/site.com.error.log notice;
}
```

I'm really confused. What's going on here?

Comment: `if (!-e $request_filename)` <- you should just be using using try_files to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because of the prefix match (`^~`) on the location block and [nginx is skipping the regex check](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then
>   regular expressions are not checked

Try removing the prefix check i.e:

```
location /_links/ { 
Regex here 
}
```

Also ***remove*** the *root declaration* inside the `location /_links/ block` you don't need it, see [nginx pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) for more information, basically servers `root declaration` is used then location is matched `$root/$location`

Also as suggested above have a look at the `try_files` directive instead  of the `if(condition){match}`

I.e. instead of:

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

A better solution would be:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri;
```

This is also mentioned in the [nginx pitfalls wiki page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Comment: Thanks - this got me to the right place. That pitfalls link is great, I was reading it and not understanding before.

Comment: My pleasure, there are a few little things that you can do to the example config you posted, just to clean up and remove unnecessary lines or blocks and make it easier to read. You should be able to read from the resources I posted, to work out what you can do and and how best to format it to your liking.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid nested locations if possible. Rewrite the `location ^~ /_links/` to the `location ^~ /_links/.*\.php` and I hope this is all you need. And it will be even better if you will use only one location for *.php, probably moving some of your rewrites there.

Comment: `if a user goes to site.com/_links/221312, then the index.php script from /_links takes over` I think you've _maybe_ misunderstood the question, or perhaps a more complete example would clarify what change you mean to be made. (Also: there's nothing necessarily wrong with nested location blocks).

Comment: yeah, there's nothing wrong with the mess in general. only that it's wrong. nobody will understand tonns of nested locations, considering the fact that they could be avoided. if the goal is that nobody except you should understand that, then you're  taking the right path.

Comment: In what way are nested location blocks wrong. -1 to encourage you to explain with reasons, rather than an offhand insult =).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Comment: @AD7six I think the general consensus is whilst **nested locations** are allowed by the configuration file parser, their use is discouraged and may produce unexpected results. This is all down to the nginx configuration inheritance model [link](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2012/08/understanding-the-nginx-configuration-inheritance-model/)

Comment: Sometimes there are situations were using a **nested location block** seems to be the only solution and simple, single **nested location blocks** solve the issue but relying on this as an acceptable solution is not recommended as applying this solution to other problems can cause unexpected results such as inheritance issues, which can be problematic and difficult to troubleshoot. Normally with understanding and research, alternative solutions can be found but if the nested solution is simple and works without issue's it is generally accepted.

Comment: @devatnull well, my point is not "I think nested location blocks are right" - it is to _edit the answer_ to explain or at least hint what problems or pitfalls they can cause instead of just saying "they bad. bad and wrong. badwrong, or badong. Yes nested location blocks are badong.". Using exaggerated examples, straw-man arguments, and a random link about reducing complexity (in comments) doesn't do that.